# Is there a way to download all the minecraft saves from PSN+?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there a way to download all the minecraft saves from PSN+? I'd like to put some of them on the Xbox one and pc and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Awnser:** No

**Explanation:**

this is mainly because the framework/build of the PSN, XBox and PC version are completely different, and incompatible with each other.

**I.e.:**

If i have an circle, a cube and a retangle, the retangle does not fit in the slot for the circle, see it the same way with almost every console games that have ports to other consoles and PC.